# Simple webpage to show statuses

Tags: monitoring, html

I am writing few automation tests. What I want to do is to create some kind of super simple web page which will show the statuses of all the test runs. For example if test passed - there will be green button near this application name, red button in case of fail accordingly. What is the most simple and straightforward way to accomplish this task? Again, I just need a column of names with green or red button near each test name.

I already created a text file which is being updated with 0 or 1 in case of success and fail. The first idea was to base the web page on this file, but I have no idea how.

The file looks like that (if it's relevant):

```
APP1 0
APP2 1 
APP2 1
.
.
.
```

Comment: You are already wrting automation tests? So what's the problem implementing this website? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, as I explained, I have already running few tests which run and write their statuses to a file. I just want these statuses be represented as a webpage. I'm not even sure it will be a real webpage, maybe just local HTML file which will be modified to present different data all the time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just modify your program to output html instead of plain text.

Your example will become something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>APP1</td> <td><img src="red.png"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>APP2</td> <td><img src="green.png"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>APP2</td> <td><img src="green.png"/></td></tr>
            ......
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's very easy to achieve this, just open the file and write all the html code until `<table>` then execute all your tests and for each one output a table row. When you have write all of them just close the remaining tags.

Obviously if you can't modify your program then you need to start from the output file that you already have, read one line at a time and split the app name from the result, then proceed as explained before.

Comment: Can you give an example of similar page but with images instead of the text? For example if I have two small button images, one is red and one is green? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the `<img>` tag. I will update the example above. You can learn more about html here http://www.w3schools.com/